# Never use Ni-MH batteries in a toy?

Tags: batteries, battery-operated

This is a simple battery powered toy basically just a DC motor.

[Never use Ni-MH Batteries](https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/10/21/21607697/21607697_3a105f3e-9e0f-4086-b55e-cab7d27e6602.jpg)

Why would Tamiya 4WD JR prohibite rechargable Ni-MH batteries? As I understand it, the voltage is a bit lower, but beyond potentially lesser performance, I see no danger. Thoughts?

[image: Never use]

Comment: This model uses AA batteries, the reasoncould be that NiMh cant cope with the current requirements of the motor. They would run out so fast and their lifespan could be compromised, too. If you replace the AA for D size NiMh maybe it could work better.

Comment: You can try asking them. I can't come up with any plausible reason, except that NiMH are capable of delivering more power if some type of fault occurs.

Comment: Oh, yeah, what @mguima said is a good point. A lot of C and D NiMH batteries are really just AA batteries in a shell. You can tell by the capacity (2-2.5 Ah).

Comment: @mkeith you re right. I was editing my post when you posted your comment. I said that a D or C size NiMh "could" work, but really your point about an AA in a greater shell is perfectly correct.

Comment: NiMh batteries do have a lower charge point, so a conventional charger may overcharge them. A proper charger would source a lower voltage and sense battery temperature as well.

Comment: Well anything bigger than AA won't fit so that's moot. For a toy like this which is just a Stomper 4x4, it will go thru Alkaline batteries like Cheetos. I want to use NiMH for cost reasons.

Comment: You _can_ use NiMH, but to protect the motor and wiring you should install an over-current protection device. A PTC fuse rated for 1.5~2A should do the trick. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This model has a low quality metal-brushed 'toy' motor which has very limited lifespan. It doesn't appear to have a current limiter or overload cutout, and is probably controlled by a simple on/off switch.

Alkaline cells have higher *nominal* voltage than NimH, but under heavy load a good NiMH will produce higher voltage for longer. In the graph below the performance of a Sanyo Eneloop (low self-disharge NiMH) and high capacity NiMH are compared to a typical Alkaline cell at 1A discharge. The alkaline can only manage about half an hour at an average voltage below 1.2V, whereas the high capacity NiMH gets over 2 hours mostly above 1.2V. The Eneloop is even more powerful, but has slightly shorter run time due to its smaller capacity.

[image]

The extended run time and higher voltage from NiMH would wear the motor out faster, and if stalled the battery could deliver enough current to burn out the motor and/or wiring. Apart from the potential fire risk, the result would be an unhappy customer who might blame the manufacturer for producing a poorly designed toy.

By specifying Alkaline only, Tamiya avoids having to improve the electronics to work with better batteries. At the time that this model was designed ([1987](http://mini-4wd.wikia.com/wiki/Lunch_Box_Jr.)) good quality motors and sophisticated electronic devices were relatively expensive, so that may have been a wise decision.

Comment: Bruce, excellent answer. How many seconds of being stalled will it take for the motor burn out? It's common when playing with these that the truck will hit an obstacle and stop. Interestingly from my parts box as a kid, I have a bunch of burned out metal brushed toy motors...

Comment: Adding simple current limiter circuit would help. Right? Then it would be safe to use NiMH batteries.

Comment: Bruce, your resettable fuse component is a good simple idea. Two ideas: perhaps I could install that under the body? They are small cars so there isn't much space. Another idea, on my vintage Stompers, they have a mini incandescent lightbulb, does that add current overload protection?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott, another thought: Energizer AA are 2000, while AAA are 700 mAh, so the AAA are close to the same as alkaline AA. Perhaps just get a slug case?

Comment: "on my vintage Stompers, they have a mini incandescent lightbulb, does that add current overload protection?" - perhaps. Is the bulb is series with the battery/motor?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I am not sure. http://www.route21.com/stompers/gen1/inside_gen1.jpg Shows the innards.  I suspect not as I don't remember a dead Stomper due to a light but I have only a couple left though so not sure.